# Iterate through array forwards then backwards

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
=>1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1
=>1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,3 #I need to be able to reverse the iteration at certain points
```

I first tried something like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.each {|i|
  if i % 9 == 0
  a.reverse!
}
```

but that just reverses the entire array and starts counting from the index it left off on. I need to to shift the direction of `each`, so to speak.

Comment: `(arr + arr[0...-1].rotate).each &method(:puts)`

Comment: what do you mean by 'solution in brute force'?

Comment: You need to make clear how the "certain points" to reverse are specified.

Comment: @kimmmo I don't know, really. I'm only a beginner. The challenge said to use brute force instead of trying to find the "trick" to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's a moving "cursor" for your array:

```
module Cursor
  def current_index
    @current_index ||= 0
  end

  def step
    @current_index = current_index + direction
    handle_boundary
  end

  def step_back
    @current_index = current_index + (direction * -1)
    handle_boundary
  end

  def handle_boundary
    if current_index == length || current_index == 0
      turn_around
    end
  end

  def direction
    @direction ||= 1
  end

  def turn_around
    @direction = direction * -1
  end

  def current
    self[current_index]
  end
end
```

And here's how you use it:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
arary.extend Cursor
array.current     # returns the item in current position
array.step        # moves a step forward, turns around when it reaches either end of the array
array.step_back   # moves a step backward without switching the direction
array.turn_around # switch the direction
```

Now you can travel around as you want :D

Comment: `direction * -1` is equivalent to `-direction`, no need for multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

```
i, counter = 0, 1                   # initialize index to 0, counter to 1 
while(i < a.length && i >= 0) do
  puts a[i]
  i+= counter                       # increment counter
  counter*= -1 if(condition)        # Multiply counter with -1 to reverse it
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Enumerator` class to create custom enumerable that can providing custom iteration through the array.  In below code, I am monkey-patching `Array` class for convenience (also due to resemblance of the method to `Array#cycle`), though solution can be done without monkey-patching as well.

```
class Array
  def reversible_cycle
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      index = 0
      direction = :forward
      loop do
        direction = :backward if index + 1 >= size
        direction = :forward if index <= 0
        y << self[index]
        index += (direction == :forward ? +1 : -1)
      end
    end
  end
end


p [1,2,3,4,5].reversible_cycle.take(9)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

p [1,2,3,4,5].reversible_cycle.take(13)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

p [1,2,3,4,5].reversible_cycle.take(17)
#> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

p [1,2,3,4,5].reversible_cycle.take(21)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For scenarios where you are changing direction without iterating the array fully in one direction, you will have to give some examples so that one can see how to modify the above code to accommodate that

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ruby's under-appreciated [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop).

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

sz = arr.size
(2*sz-1).times { |i| puts i==0..i==arr.size-1 ? arr[i] : arr[sz-i-2] }
1
2
3
4
5
4
3
2
1
```